# Has the answer to PopSci's question "How Many Years Does The Space Station Have Left?" been published?

Tags: iss, reentry, end-of-life

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/24429/12102) to the question *Why does the ISS have to be destroyed?* begins

> It doesn't, not really, but there will come a time when it will simply not be worth keeping it up.

and mentions a study, and provides the link to the 2015 Popular Science article [How Many Years Does The Space Station Have Left?](https://www.popsci.com/how-many-years-does-space-station-have-left)

Is the study finished? Has it published an answer?

Comment: Boeing is now looking for funding for a second study to determine whether the first study can be extended through 2028.

Comment: @RussellBorogove it sounds like you may know the answer to this question then?

Comment: I’m now seeking funding for a study to determine whether the rumors of a second Boeing study are substantiated, or simply weak attempts at humor.

Comment: @RussellBorogove Ack! I've been burned again :D